# swapon failed: Device or resource busy on mounted disk

Tags: ubuntu

I want to make a swap on mounted external EBS, /workspace

And I got **Device or resource busy**

swapon: /workspace/swap.1: swapon failed: Device or resource busy

```
sudo /bin/dd if=/dev/zero of=/workspace/swap.1 bs=1M count=10240
sudo /sbin/mkswap /workspace/swap.1
sudo /sbin/swapon /workspace/swap.1


Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      7.8G  5.1G  2.3G  70% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            2.0G   12K  2.0G   1% /dev
tmpfs           396M  336K  395M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/xvdb       6.0T  1.7T  4.1T  29% /workspace
```

Still not working after running `sync` command

```
➜  ~  sync
➜  ~  sudo /sbin/swapon /workspace/swap.1
swapon: /workspace/swap.1: swapon failed: Device or resource busy
```

Here's the swap information

```
➜  ~   cat /proc/swaps
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/workspace/swap.1                       file        10485756    0   -1
```

Comment: It may already have been added.  Could you cut-and-paste the output of `cat /proc/swaps` into your **question**?

Comment: @MadHatter Hi I updated the info.

Comment: @poc Swapping was on it already turned on... it probably remained from a previous try. Before your next try, turn off swap with a `swapoff /workspace/swap.1`. Glory belongs to MadHatter.

Comment: "Swap on, swap off, Daniel-San", like Mr. Miyagi taught the young kid still in his early steps to mastering server-fu.

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar issue trying to make a swap partition on sda2. My solution was to type

```
#: swapoff /dev/sda2
#: mkswap /dev/sda2
#: swapon /dev/sda2
```

This seemed to reset whatever issue I was having. To make sure this worked, use "*lsblk*" to check the mountpoint.

Comment: It works for me.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not adding the swap; the problem is your assumption that all swap space shows up in the output of `df`.

Only partition-type data shows up in that, and as you're using in-system swapping, aka a swapfile, it doesn't show up.  The swap space *was* activated by the first `swapon` you did; you were just looking in the wrong place to confirm that.  The second `swapon` failed, quite rightly, because you can't add the same file a second time.  When you looked in `/proc/swaps`, which is the definitive system summary of **all** swap space, you saw that your new space was up and running.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `sync` out the block cache after the `mkswap` command.

Its explanation is the following.

If you write data, but they aren't written out into the disk physically, they will be dirty pages. It means, that their content was created here, on your system, and wasn't read in from the hard disk. Thus you can't swap on dirty pages.

Comment: your solution not works :(

Comment: @poc In similar cases it is the solution, but MadHatter's idea seems very fruitful.

Answer (score 0):

try this command

```
echo 1 > /sys/block/zram0/reset
```

replace "zram0" with your swap partition. example:

```
    # Zram disk - 512MB size
#zram_enable=`getprop ro.config.zram`
#if [ "$zram_enable" == "true" ]; then
#    swapoff /dev/block/zram0
#    echo 1 > /sys/block/zram0/reset
#    echo 536870912 > /sys/block/zram0/disksize
#    mkswap /dev/block/zram0
#    sync
#    swapon /dev/block/zram0 -p 32758
```